# How to connect two docker containers together

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `reactjs` front end application and a simple `python` `flask`. And I am using a `docker-compose.yml` to spin up both the containers, and it is like this:

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  frontend:
    build: .
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - "backend:backend"
    depends_on:
      - backend 

  backend: 
    build: ./api
    # volumes:
      # - ./api:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      # CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
      FLASK_APP: /usr/src/app/server.py
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    ports: 
      - 8083:8083
```

I have used `links` so the `frontend` service can talk to `backend` service using `axios` as below:

```
axio.get("http://backend:8083/monitors").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        status: res.data
      });
    });
```

I used `docker-compose up  --build -d` to build and start the two containers and they are started without any issue and running fine.

But now the `frontend` cannot talk to `backend`.

I am using an `AWS` ec2 instance. When the page loads, I tried to see the for any console errors and I get this error:

> VM167:1 GET http://backend:8083/monitors net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Can someone please help me?

The `backend` service is up and running.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, the hostname `backend` is only known to the container and not to the client. This works only if you run your code on the container itself (serverside).

Comment: So what is the workaround? Can my containers not talk to each other? What if server Ip changes? I don't want to use a static ip though.

Comment: Your containers can talk to each other but the client is not able to. I would recommend to put an reverse proxy (like nginx) infront of both and work with that. If the proxy is also a container you can use the backend hostname

Comment: I am using `nginx` proxy. How the configuration should look like?

Comment: @Spirit Client is able to... Clients can use ports exposed from containers directly via `ports` directive.

Comment: @DanielHornik but the client is not able to resolve the hostname

Comment: Ahhh, correct, but no proxy is required, just modify host entries. `/etc/hosts` for linux. Add those 2 lines: `127.0.0.1 backend` and `127.0.0.1 frontend`

Comment: Where should I add these hostnames? in the `aws` ec2 instance?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nginx as reverse proxy for both

The compose file

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    depends_on:
      - backend 

  backend: 
    build: ./api
    # volumes:
      # - ./api:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      # CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
      FLASK_APP: /usr/src/app/server.py
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1

  proxy: 
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf
    ports: 
      - 80:80
```

minimal nginx config (nginx.conf):

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:80;
    }
}

server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8083;
    }
}
```

The request hits the nginx container and is routed according the domain to the right container.

To use example.com and api.example.com you need to edit your hosts file:

Linux: `/etc/hosts` 
Windows: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` 
Mac: `/private/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 example.com api.example.com
```

Comment: Where should I do the changes `/etc/hosts` ? In my local computer (client machine?) or?

Comment: yes, your client machine, if this code is going in production, you need a valid domain and an dns entry.

Comment: What is advantage here over the add `127.0.0.1 backend` and the same for frontend? It creates more complexity, but We do not know if author wants to expose backend to customers.

Comment: @DanielHornik You can use this setup also on production. The author needs to expose the backend to the customer, because the customer needs to talk to the backend. Your solution to map the `backend` does nothing else except use the internal hostname mappings. You can also apply further restrictions with nginx.

Comment: But why do I need to put any entries in `/etc/hosts`. So that means, whoever access that page needs to put entries in their machines? This is practically not possible

Comment: the hosts file is only for development. In Production you need to use a valid domain and point it to the server. Put this is another topic.